# How to have drag and drop file feature for QlistWidget along with internal move option in PyQt

Tags: python, qt, drag-and-drop, pyqt

I have made a QListWidget which accepts files by drag and drop method. But once I enable this feature , then the previously set **internalMove** option of ListWidget to sort the list element by the user won't work.

```

```
class draglist(QtGui.QListWidget):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        super(draglist,self).__init__(parent);
        self.setAcceptDrops(True);
        self.setDragDropMode(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.InternalMove);
        self.setDefaultDropAction(QtCore.Qt.MoveAction);


    def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
        print("Enter event") ;
        data = event.mimeData()
        # QtCore.QMimeData.text

        if event.mimeData().hasUrls():
            event.accept()
        else:
            print("ignored");
            event.ignore()

    def dragMoveEvent(self, event):

        print("mouse move event happening") ;
        print(event.mimeData())

        print(event.mimeData().formats());

        if event.mimeData().hasUrls():
            event.setDropAction(QtCore.Qt.CopyAction)
            event.accept()

        else:
                print("ignored");
                event.ignore()

    def dropEvent(self, event):


        if event.mimeData().hasUrls():
            event.setDropAction(QtCore.Qt.CopyAction)
            event.accept()
            links=[]
            for url in event.mimeData().urls():
                links.append(str(url.toLocalFile()))

            self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL("dropped"),links)

        else:
            event.ignore()
```

```

The above code works fine for drag and drop operation of any files and puts all the dropped files in a list called `links`.

But when I try to move the list items internally after the list is populated with the file names got from links list , I am not able to move the list items internally to sort the items in the list . How to do this while the drag and drop of files feature is enabled ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It may have to do with your using a local variable in dropEvent(). The lifetime of this variable is only until the end of that function, and the value of `links` may not be accessed until later (signals are asynchronous). By that point the list may be destroyed. I'm not sure if this is the problem, but try replacing links with an instance variable of draglist, e.g `self.links`, that is initialized in the class `__init__()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using the `event.ignore` in the `else` statement :-

```
else:
   print("ignored");
   event.ignore()
```

Becoz of this , even if the internal move behavior is enabled, when the user tries to do anything other than drag and drop files ,  It ignores all the events which make the internal move possible. So , the solution is to **not ignore** the event but to inherit from the already present event if the hasUrls() returns false . Here is the full code solution for this .

```
class draglist(QtGui.QListWidget):

    def __init__(self,parent):
        super(draglist,self).__init__(parent);
        self.setAcceptDrops(True);
        self.setDragDropMode(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.InternalMove)
        self.setDefaultDropAction(QtCore.Qt.MoveAction)

    def dragEnterEvent(self, event):

        if event.mimeData().hasUrls():
            event.acceptProposedAction() ;
        else:
            super(draglist,self).dragEnterEvent(event);


    def dragMoveEvent(self, event):
        super(draglist,self).dragMoveEvent(event);


    def dropEvent(self, event):

        if event.mimeData().hasUrls():
            event.setDropAction(QtCore.Qt.CopyAction)
            event.accept()
            links=[]
            for url in event.mimeData().urls():
                links.append(str(url.toLocalFile()))

            self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL("dropped"),links)
        else:
            super(draglist,self).dropEvent(event);
```

In the list function which catches this signal do this :-

`MainWindow.connect(ui.fileListWidget , QtCore.SIGNAL("dropped") ,self.handledrop)`

```
def handledrop(self,links):
        for url in links:
            if os.path.exists(url):
                item = QtGui.QListWidgetItem(url, ui.fileListWidget)
```